# The average outcome of the sum of a pair of dice and the higher sum of two pairs

Tags: probability, dice

I'm helping my son to design a game using dice. He wants to figure out the expected outcome of the sum of a pair of $6$-sided dice, if $2$ pairs of dice are thrown and the higher pair is kept.

I get as far as the expected outcome of a single pair of dice is $7$ by calculating the weighted average of all $36$ outcomes.

Where do we go from here, to account for taking the higher of $2$ pairs of $6$-sided dice?

Comment: For a single pair, why are there 216 out comes? There should be 36. Also, when it comes to expectation, it is additive. So if one dice's expected value is 3.5, then a pair would be 7.

Comment: @Indominus: But the OP wants the expectation when you choose the larger sum of the two pairs of dice. That complicates things.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I understand, but I can't work out an elegant solution for her question, so just giving a side comment. The best solution I can find for her question is to enumerate all 11 possible outcomes for pair 1 and sum up, which means basically enumerate all 121 out comes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see several ways to handle this.

1. Look at all $6^4=1296$ possible values of the four dice and average these values. No weights are necessary since the outcomes are equally likely.
2. Look at all $11^2=121$ possible sums of the two dice. Each pair of dice can sum from $2$ through $12$, which is $11$ possible values. You would then calculate the weighted average of these outcomes. Weights are necessary here.
3. Look at all $11$ possible final outcomes, $2$ through $12$, and take the weighted average of these outcomes. For example, the final total $2$ happens only when both pair of dice sum to $2$, with probability $\frac 1{36}\cdot\frac 1{36}=\frac 1{1296}$. The final total $7$ happens when the first pair sums to $7$ and the second pair sums to $7$ or less, with probability $\frac 16\cdot\frac{21}{36}=\frac 7{72}$, or when the first pair sums to less than $7$ and the second pair sums to $7$, with probability $\frac{15}{36}\cdot\frac 16=\frac 5{72}$. These add up to probability $\frac 16$. You could also calculate this as twice the probability that one pair sums to $7$ and the other sums to at most $7$ less the probability that both pair sum to $7$, which is $2\cdot\frac 16\cdot\frac{21}{36}-\left(\frac 16\right)^2=\frac 16$. Clearly weights are needed here and finding them is the hard part.

Option three seems the easiest here if you are doing this by hand, option one is easiest if you use a computer program or spreadsheet.

Doing option 1 on a spreadsheet, I get the value $\frac{10850}{1296}=\frac{5425}{648}=8+\frac{241}{648}\approx 8.37191358$. I get the same answer doing option 2 and option 3 on a spreadsheet. Option 3 was easier than I expected: let me know if you want a copy of the quick-and-dirty Excel spreadsheet I made that does all three options.

Answer (score 1):

Use fact that cdf of max is product of cdfs.

In R:

```
> die = c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
> dice = convolve(die,die,type="o")
> dice
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
> dice.pdf = dice/36
> dice.pdf
 [1] 0.02777778 0.05555556 0.08333333 0.11111111 0.13888889 0.16666667
 [7] 0.13888889 0.11111111 0.08333333 0.05555556 0.02777778
> dice.cdf = cumsum(dice.pdf)
> dice.cdf
 [1] 0.02777778 0.08333333 0.16666667 0.27777778 0.41666667 0.58333333
 [7] 0.72222222 0.83333333 0.91666667 0.97222222 1.00000000
> max.cdf = dice.cdf^2
> max.cdf
 [1] 0.0007716049 0.0069444444 0.0277777778 0.0771604938 0.1736111111
 [6] 0.3402777778 0.5216049383 0.6944444444 0.8402777778 0.9452160494
[11] 1.0000000000
> ev = 2 + sum(1-max.cdf)
> ev
[1] 8.371914
```

You can do that with pencil and paper by keeping those as integers until the end:

1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1

Do cumulative sum:

1  3  6 10 15 21 26 30 33 35 36

Square that:

1    9   36  100  225  441  676  900 1089 1225 1296

Subtract from 1296:

1295 1287 1260 1196 1071  855  620  396  207   71    0

Add those to get 8258.  Then

2 + 8258/1296 = 5425/648 ≈ 8.371914

Answer (score 0):

> He wants to figure out the expected outcome of the sum of a pair of dice(6 sided) if two pair of dice are thrown and the higher pair is kept.

[$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\max(X+Y, U+V)) & = \frac 1 {6^4} \sum_{x=1}^6 \sum_{y=1}^6 \sum_{u=1}^6 \sum_{v=1}^6 \max(x+y, u+v)
\\ & = \dfrac{5425}{648}
\\ & \approx 8.37191\ldots
\end{align}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Bsum+%5Bsum%5B+sum+%5Bmax%28x%2By%2Cu%2Bv%29+%2C+%7Bv%2C+1%2C+6%7D%5D%2C+%7Bu%2C+1%2C+6%7D%5D%2C+%7By%2C+1%2C+6%7D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+1%2C+6%7D%5D+%2F+6%5E4)

Comment: I did it in Excel, a solution of now mathematical beauty, but it gets the number - about 8.37, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

A short Python script might be useful here:

```
sum = 0

for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
    for j in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
        for m in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
            for n in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
                sum += i+j if i+j > m+n else m+n

print float(sum) / 6**4
```

The result is $8.37191358025$.